# tcolorbox 0pt wide lines visible in some PDF viewers

Tags: pdf, tcolorbox

After compiling my document, boxes that should have some of the lines invisible (0 pt) have them still visible in some PDF viewers, namely Ubuntu's Evince, Firefox's default PDF viewer, and others. This is not visible in TeXmaker's preview, nor Okular. How can I prevent their visibility?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable=true,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    colback=white,
    rightrule=0pt,
    leftrule=2pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    right=-3pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    colframe=black,
    enlarge left by=15pt,
    width=\linewidth - 15pt]

    \lipsum
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

TeXmaker preview:

[image: correct]

Evince:

[image: incorrect]

Comment: You are aware that your code is not compilable. There is no document around...

Comment: Yes, but its part of a quite long custom package. I posted only the tcolorbox that has issues. I'll edit my question and add info about loaded packages, but I don't think all code is necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `enhanced jigsaw` option. This improves the line drawing/suppression and the hidden frame parts are not visible in `Acrobat`, `evince` and FireFox preview.

This does not mean, that there aren't any lines visible in other PDF viewers. I can't check for others.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable=true,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    colback=white,
    rightrule=0pt,
    leftrule=2pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    right=-3pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    colframe=black,
    enlarge left by=15pt,
    width=\linewidth - 15pt]
\blindtext

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The 'enhanced jigsaw' option may be helpful when the background color is the same as the page color, if not however, it doesn't help much, as the colored boxes above and below still have a hair-thin seam between them visible in some viewers.

Answer (score 8):

Christian Hupfer already gave an answer with the `enhanced jigsaw` option which is always preferable, if the box has some `0pt` lines.

For your special application, you can use `empty` as an alternative. This skin simply draws nothing. The black rule can be added by `borderline west`. This way, there should be no ghost line with any previewer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    empty,
    breakable=true,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    % colback=white,
    rightrule=0pt,
    leftrule=2pt,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black},
    toprule=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    right=-3pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    % colframe=black,
    enlarge left by=15pt,
    width=\linewidth - 15pt]
\blindtext

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was already in `enhanced jigsaw` but the `empty` mode fixed the bug. Thanks a lot!